# For loop is returning only last value

Tags: r

For the below for loop I am able to see all values. But when I assign new object to it, the value returned is only last (Refer last code). can anyone help me here please. Is it not possible to all values displayed with assigning a value?

```
for(i in 1:5)
+ {
+     for(j in 1:2)
+     {
+         print(i*j);
+     }
+ }
```

Assigned a object.

```
for(i in 1:5)
+ {
+     for(j in 1:2)
+     {
+         as <- i*j
+     }
+ }
```

Comment: Where would you like to store all values?  The dummy variable `as` is just a scalar, and can only hold a single value.  The value you see at the end of the loop just reflects the final assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need to store in as object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a canonical R way of doing this:

```
as.vector(seq(1:2)%*%t(seq(1:5)))

[1]  1  2  2  4  3  6  4  8  5 10
```

This approach takes the dot product product between `[1,2]` and `t[1,2,3,4,5]`.  Instead of using explicit loops, it used vectors to represent the bounds of your two original loops.  The intermediate result is a matrix, which we can easily convert to a 1D vector in either column or row order, depending on the bounds of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

**`for` loop approach**

If you want to append new values to `as`, you can try to update `as` by `as <- c(as,i*j)`, which concatenates `i*j` with existing `as` and the result is assigned to `as`, i.e.,

```
as <- c()
for(i in 1:5)
{
     for(j in 1:2)
     {
         as <- c(as,i*j)
     }
}
```

**`outer` approach**

A more efficient way to achieve the same goal can be using `outer`, i.e.,

```
as <- c(t(outer(1:5,1:2)))
```

Comment: Thanks will check 

Comment: Please, be aware that this solution is highly inefficient and should be done in another way.

Comment: @Georgery I added an efficient solution

Comment: Thanks guys . Actually I’m performing some shiny tests so it’s required to be under for loop. Let me check on the solution 

Answer (score 0):

So, the `for` loop is very inefficient here. You should multiply vectors instead. E.g.

```
 rep(1:5, each = 2)
```

gives you

```
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

and if you multiply this with

```
1:2
```

the shorter vector gets recycled and you get this:

```
rep(1:5, each = 2) * 1:2
[1]  1  2  2  4  3  6  4  8  5 10
```